# How to parse this JSON string

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to parse this string into java, but I keep getting errors.

```
{"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"limits":{"end":3,"start":0,"total":3},"sources":[{"file":"/media/storage/media/re Music/","label":"re Music"},{"file":"/media/storage/media/ra Music/","label":"ra Music"},{"file":"addons://sources/audio/","label":"Music Add-ons"}]}}
```

When I use this code ...

```
String temp = //json code returned from up above
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(temp);
JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("sources");
```

I get an error saying org.json.JSONObject Value... and then displays what is in temp. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array named "sources" is several levels deep. You need to traverse down into the json.

Code formatters help with this stuff...

http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

```
{
   "id":1,
   "jsonrpc":"2.0",
   "result":{
      "limits":{
         "end":3,
         "start":0,
         "total":3
      },
      "sources":[
         {
            "file":"/media/storage/media/re Music/",
            "label":"re Music"
         },
         {
            "file":"/media/storage/media/ra Music/",
            "label":"ra Music"
         },
         {
            "file":"addons://sources/audio/",
            "label":"Music Add-ons"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: ok that makes more sense, but how would go into a nested statement like this?

like this?

JSONArray ar = obj.getaray("results")

Comment: @user987103 what is `getarray`? What is `"results"`?

Comment: I don't know the details of the exact library you are using, (you haven't actully told us though I probably could figure it out from the package name). Typically, you would do obj.get("result").getArray("sources"). Check your javadoc for the exact specifics on method namees

Comment: oh I'm just using org.json .. is there an easier one to use?

Comment: There are lots out there, but there are lots of stack overflow questions adressing the pros and cons. Which line gives you the error, the second or the third (in your original code)

Comment: the second one. It says that the type of JSONArray can not be converted to JSONObject. I know what that means, but is it saying that the temp string which is the result is an array? If so, how would I convert it using the standard Java JSON library? thanks for your help.. I've been stuck on this for a little bit

Comment: Are you dead sure you have given us exactly the text, it sounds like you have this problem (note the [] on the outside of this guy's json response) http://www.anddev.org/view-layout-resource-problems-f27/json-parsing-error-help-t48453.html

Comment: i think that by doing this

JSONObject obj = new JSONArray(temp).getJSONObject(0);
JSONArray dir = obj.getJSONArray("result");

worked.. but now the issue is at my loop. I should use another JSONArray to find the "source" array? and then use that source array in my loop to get the contents right?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the "sources" array is in the "result" object.  So you would need to get that object and then get the array from that like this:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(temp);
JSONObject result = obj.getJSONObject("result");
JSONArray array = result.getJSONArray("sources");
```

Comment: everytime I put the result string into a JSONObject it throws that same exception

Answer (score 0):

Your json should have top level object, from there you need to get child objects. See this [link](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/10/json-parsing-in-android/) for more detail.

Comment: that's the thing though, once I put that temp string into a JSONObject it throws an error. I know that I have to go into a nested result, but it just throws that error.